# Occasionally got “Request timed out” when trying to do ping test on a LAN server. What likely will be the cause?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, ping

I want to troubleshoot what causing the connection unstable between workstation and server in a LAN. When i try do the ping test, the reply sometime “Request timed out.” Any idea what likely the cause of this issue?

I tried change network adapter, change network cable, change network port, reassign different IP address to the server. Still the result remain. I got another server on the same rack and same IP segment (base), but the other server is okay.

Any idea on this guys?

Comment: How often is occasionally?

Comment: In 30 ping request, 10 request is timed out....

Comment: I'd suggest using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to investigate the problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestuon. Run the wireshark on the workstation or server? I unable to access the server right now...

Comment: If multiple workstations can't reach the server while pinging it, you'll probably need to run Wireshark on the server to investigate further. If a particular workstation is having trouble reaching the server while others aren't, you might want to run Wireshark on that workstation.

Comment: Compare the parameters on the server interface and the port on the LAN switch. Are both on full duplex? Are both at the same speed? If you can, disable auto speed on LAN port and interface and set them manually to a fixed value.